# Converting a distinct list to dictionary not working

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a list of objects to a dictionary using the following code:

```
 var MyDictionary = MyList.Distinct().ToDictionary(i => i.ObjectId, i => i);
```

I know that a dictionary should not contain duplicate elements, hence the `.Distinct()`. Yet I still get the following Exception whenever there's a duplicate element:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

`MyList` is a list of MyObject that looks like this:

```
public class MyObject{

        public string ObjectId { get; set; }

        public string FName { get; set; }

        public string LName { get; set; }

    }
```

Is there a better way to create a dictionary from a list of objects ? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to group by `ObjectId` instead of calling `Distinct`.  Either you have multiple references to the same object or multiple objects that have the same `ObjectId`.

Comment: i.e, just because your `MyObject` do not compare equal (.Distinct) does not mean that their `ObjectIds` aren't equal.

Comment: @DStanley which solution would be more efficient? using a groupBy or custom comparer with Distinct() ?

Comment: @MrX neither is more efficient, they do two different jobs.

Comment: @MrX You'd have to try it both ways and measure to be sure, but I wouldn't expect that there would be a huge performance difference to the overall performance of the system.  The main advantage of a custom comparer is that it's _reusable_.  So if you do this in many places it simplifies the code.

Comment: [C# Distinct by propery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property) contains plenty of ways to actually do `Distinct` you are looking for.

Comment: @DStanley this makes sense, Thanks. I did test it out of a fairly large dataset and it  hardly had any difference in performance. For the sake of re-usability and readability I will use a custom comparer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to compare on the ObjectId, you'll need to pass in a custom comparer to `.Distinct()`. You can do so like this:

```
class MyObjectComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyObject>
{
    public bool Equals(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        return x.ObjectId == y.ObjectId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyObject obj)
    {
        return obj.ObjectId.GetHashCode();
    }
}

var MyDictionary = MyList
    .Distinct(new MyObjectComparer())
    .ToDictionary(i => i.ObjectId, i => i);
```

Comment: You need to implement `GeHashCode` properly as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Group by and then select first from the List as below:

```
var MyDictionary = MyList.GroupBy(i => i.ObjectId, i => i).ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.First());
```

Comment: You don't need the `i => i` parameter as the `GroupBy` that only takes one lambda does that by default.

Comment: Yes thats true, its not needed, but I wrote it just in case if User wants to select a specific variable in place of the whole object. So they could use the second argument in the Group by to select a specific variable or full object like:    
**MyList.GroupBy(i => i.ObjectId, i => (i.FName + i.LName))**

Answer (score 1):

Distinct works using the objects built in `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods by default but your dictionary works only over the id. You need to pass in a `IEqualityComparer` in to distinct that does the comparison on `Id` to test if items are equal or make `MyObject` implment `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and have that compare on the `Id`.